# How do I reduce repeated generic specification?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

In this example, I repeat `na::SVector<f64, NumStates>` a bunch, can I define a type

```
type StateVector = na::SVector<f64, NumStates>;
```

like this? I get an error that `associated type defaults are unstable`. Is there another way?

```
use nalgebra as na;

pub trait Cost<const NumStates: usize, const NumControls: usize> {
    fn stage_cost(&self, x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>, u: &na::SVector<f64, NumControls>)
        -> f64;
    fn stage_grad(
        &self,
        x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
        u: &na::SVector<f64, NumControls>,
        grad_x: &mut na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
        grad_u: &mut na::SVector<f64, NumControls>,
    );
    fn terminal_cost(&self, x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>) -> f64;
    fn terminal_grad(
        &self,
        x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
        grad: &mut na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
    );
}
```

Comment: `type` inside a trait creates an associated type. Outside, it creates an alias. You probably want to define it outside of the trait.

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter points out, position matters.  I suspect your codeblock creating the error looks like this:

```rust
use nalgebra as na;

pub trait Cost<const NumStates: usize, const NumControls: usize> {
    type StateVector = na::SVector<f64, NumStates>;

    fn stage_cost(&self, x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>, u: &na::SVector<f64, NumControls>)
        -> f64;
    fn stage_grad(
        &self,
        x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
        u: &na::SVector<f64, NumControls>,
        grad_x: &mut na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
        grad_u: &mut na::SVector<f64, NumControls>,
    );
    fn terminal_cost(&self, x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>) -> f64;
    fn terminal_grad(
        &self,
        x: &na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
        grad: &mut na::SVector<f64, NumStates>,
    );
}
```

This creates an *associated type* which cannot have a default type on stable.

Define your type alias *outside* of the `trait` body and you've solved your problem:

```rust
use algebra as na;

type StateVector<const D: usize> = na::SVector<f64, D>;

pub trait Cost<const NumStates: usize, const NumControls: usize> {
    fn stage_cost(&self, x: &StateVector<NumStates>, u: &StateVector<NumControls>)
        -> f64;
    fn stage_grad(
        &self,
        x: &StateVector<NumStates>,
        u: &StateVector<NumControls>,
        grad_x: &mut StateVector<NumStates>,
        grad_u: &mut StateVector<NumControls>,
    );
    fn terminal_cost(&self, x: &StateVector<NumStates>) -> f64;
    fn terminal_grad(
        &self,
        x: &StateVector<NumStates>,
        grad: &mut StateVector<NumStates>,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `associated type defaults are unstable` states that it is unstable to assign a default type to associated types on a trait, but you can still add associated traits without default values. So just... don't. Even if you add a default, it won't stop someone from not following your vector length requirements and changing the types upon implementing the trait.

After some tinkering here is what I came up with. I ended up shortening `StateVector` to `States` since the long name was almost as bad as the original. Plus who knows, maybe I want to try implementing your trait for my type using `std::collections::LinkedList<f64>` to hold my data.

```rust
pub trait Cost<const NUM_STATES: usize, const NUM_CONTROLS: usize> {
    type States;
    type Controls;

    fn stage_cost(&self, x: &Self::States, u: &Self::Controls) -> f64;
    fn stage_grad(
        &self,
        x: &Self::States,
        u: &Self::Controls,
        grad_x: &mut Self::States,
        grad_u: &mut Self::Controls,
    );
    fn terminal_cost(&self, x: &Self::States) -> f64;
    fn terminal_grad(&self, x: &Self::States, grad: &mut Self::States);
}
```

But then again, if we are changing the trait signature, why not skip the constants?

```rust
pub trait Cost<States, Controls> {
    fn stage_cost(&self, x: &States, u: &Controls) -> f64;
    fn stage_grad(&self, x: &States, u: &Controls, grad_x: &mut States, grad_u: &mut Controls);
    fn terminal_cost(&self, x: &States) -> f64;
    fn terminal_grad(&self, x: &States, grad: &mut States);
}
```

However, this does come at the cost of making usages of this trait longer.

```rust
// Example usage of origional
where A: Cost<S, C>,
// First suggestion
where B: Costs<S, C, States=SVector<f64, S>, Controls=SVector<f64, C>>,
// Second suggestion
where C: Costs<SVector<f64, S>, SVector<f64, C>>,
```

It may be best to leave your original as-is. That being said, one change I would make would be to import `use nalgebra::SVector` so you can remove the `na::` prefixes for the vectors.